# How do I post requests to GasBuddy's GraphQL API?

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, graphql

I saw that there was a way to request data by using a website's GraphQL API, but I'm unable to successfully query the data. Following [this](https://scrapfly.io/blog/web-scraping-graphql-with-python/) tutorial I'm unable to map the API via Apollo since they seem to have introspection disabled, but I pieced together what I've seen elsewhere using the Network data through Chrome's Inspect tool. Additionally, the `ZIP_CODE` is filled in with one I'm interested in.

Edit: The data I'm trying to extract is the `Address` of the station and the reported `Price` of regular gas.

Currently, I'm running the following script via Python:

```
import requests

url = "https://gasbuddy.com/graphql"
query = {
    "operationName": "LocationBySearchTerm",
    "variables": {
        "fuel": 1, 
        "maxAge": 0, 
        "search": "ZIP_CODE"
    },
     "query": """
query LocationBySearchTerm($brandId: Int, $cursor: String, $fuel: Int, $lat: Float, $lng: Float, $maxAge: Int, $search: String) {
  locationBySearchTerm(lat: $lat, lng: $lng, search: $search) {
    countryCode
    displayName
    latitude
    longitude
    regionCode
    stations(brandId: $brandId, cursor: $cursor, fuel: $fuel, maxAge: $maxAge) {
      count
      cursor {
        next
        __typename
      }
      results {
        address {
          country
          line1
          line2
          locality
          postalCode
          region
          __typename
        }
        badges {
          badgeId
          callToAction
          campaignId
          clickTrackingUrl
          description
          detailsImageUrl
          detailsImpressionTrackingUrls
          imageUrl
          impressionTrackingUrls
          targetUrl
          title
          __typename
        }
        brandings {
          brand_id
          branding_type
          __typename
        }
        brands {
          brand_id
          image_url
          name
          __typename
        }
        emergency_status {
          has_diesel {
            nick_name
            report_status
            update_date
            __typename
          }
          has_gas {
            nick_name
            report_status
            update_date
            __typename
          }
          has_power {
            nick_name
            report_status
            update_date
            __typename
          }
          __typename
        }
        enterprise
        fuels
        id
        name
        offers {
          discounts {
            grades
            highlight
            pwgbDiscount
            receiptDiscount
            __typename
          }
          highlight
          id
          types
          use
          __typename
        }
        pay_status {
          is_pay_available
          __typename
        }
        prices {
          cash {
            nickname
            posted_time
            price
            __typename
          }
          credit {
            nickname
            posted_time
            price
            __typename
          }
          discount
          fuel_product
          __typename
        }
        ratings_count
        star_rating
        __typename
      }
      __typename
    }
    trends {
      areaName
      country
      today
      todayLow
      trend
      __typename
    }
    __typename
}""",
}

response = requests.post(url, json=query)
print(response.json())
```

I receive a `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` error, and the response is 403. Can anyone see if my requet is formatted incorrectly?

Edit: An example of part of one of the response bodies when using the zip code 78015 is:

```
{
    "data": {
        "locationBySearchTerm": {
            "countryCode": "US",
            "displayName": "78015",
            "latitude": 29.7469487986786,
            "longitude": -98.6554815781517,
            "regionCode": "TX",
            "stations": {
                "count": 2,
                "cursor": {
                    "next": "1",
                    "__typename": "Cursor"
                },
                "results": [
                    {
                        "address": {
                            "country": "US",
                            "line1": "29202 Ralph Fair Rd",
                            "line2": "",
                            "locality": "Boerne",
                            "postalCode": "78015-4223",
                            "region": "TX",
                            "__typename": "Address"
                        },
                        "badges": [],
                        "brandings": [
                            {
                                "brand_id": "122",
                                "branding_type": "fuel",
                                "__typename": "Branding"
                            }
                        ],
                        "brands": [
                            {
                                "brand_id": "122",
                                "image_url": "https://images.gasbuddy.io/b/122.png",
                                "name": "Shell",
                                "__typename": "Brand"
                            }
                        ],
                        "emergency_status": null,
                        "enterprise": false,
                        "fuels": [
                            "regular_gas",
                            "midgrade_gas",
                            "premium_gas",
                            "diesel"
                        ],
                        "id": "64158",
                        "name": "Shell",
                        "offers": [
                            {
                                "discounts": [
                                    {
                                        "grades": [
                                            "regular_gas",
                                            "diesel"
                                        ],
                                        "highlight": "Deal Alert: Save 5¢ per gallon",
                                        "pwgbDiscount": "0.05",
                                        "receiptDiscount": "0.01",
                                        "__typename": "Discount"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "grades": [
                                            "midgrade_gas"
                                        ],
                                        "highlight": "Deal Alert: Save 5¢ per gallon",
                                        "pwgbDiscount": "0.05",
                                        "receiptDiscount": "0.01",
                                        "__typename": "Discount"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "grades": [
                                            "premium_gas"
                                        ],
                                        "highlight": "Deal Alert: Save 5¢ per gallon",
                                        "pwgbDiscount": "0.05",
                                        "receiptDiscount": "0.01",
                                        "__typename": "Discount"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "highlight": "Deal Alert: Save up to 5¢ per gallon",
                                "id": "H464158-4-4-4-5-G2-a010fa0a-1ffd-4566-9fae-2f89d3f849f0",
                                "types": [
                                    "gasbuddy",
                                    "getupside"
                                ],
                                "use": [
                                    "strike",
                                    "banner",
                                    "sort"
                                ],
                                "__typename": "Offer"
                            }
                        ],
                        "pay_status": {
                            "is_pay_available": true,
                            "__typename": "PayStatus"
                        },
                        "prices": [
                            {
                                "cash": null,
                                "credit": {
                                    "nickname": "Buddy_qdx3kktn",
                                    "posted_time": "2023-01-12T13:47:29.825Z",
                                    "price": 2.85,
                                    "__typename": "FuelPrice"
                                },
                                "discount": 0,
                                "fuel_product": "regular_gas",
                                "__typename": "PriceReport"
                            },
                            {
                                "cash": null,
                                "credit": {
                                    "nickname": "MoriSeiki",
                                    "posted_time": "2023-01-11T00:56:21.856Z",
                                    "price": 3.05,
                                    "__typename": "FuelPrice"
                                },
                                "discount": 0,
                                "fuel_product": "midgrade_gas",
                                "__typename": "PriceReport"
                            },
                            {
                                "cash": null,
                                "credit": {
                                    "nickname": "Buddy_qdx3kktn",
                                    "posted_time": "2023-01-12T13:47:29.841Z",
                                    "price": 3.49,
                                    "__typename": "FuelPrice"
                                },
                                "discount": 0,
                                "fuel_product": "premium_gas",
                                "__typename": "PriceReport"
                            },
                            {
                                "cash": null,
                                "credit": {
                                    "nickname": "ACTRAT",
                                    "posted_time": "2023-01-12T15:58:58.163Z",
                                    "price": 3.99,
                                    "__typename": "FuelPrice"
                                },
                                "discount": 0,
                                "fuel_product": "diesel",
                                "__typename": "PriceReport"
                            }
                        ],
                        "ratings_count": 61,
                        "star_rating": 4.4,
                        "__typename": "Station"
                    },...
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add what data you want to extract.

Comment: Overlooked and now edited @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes

Comment: I'm trying to understand the `query` value you're sending - looking on the internet about the error, it says it's not a correct JSON object. Can you elaborate about the values you use on the `query` variable? - also, it would be better if you add actual results examples. In this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8jV6.png) I can see various addresses and values, but, I don't know which one is the one you're looking for.

Comment: I've added an example @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes. The response is quite large. So, I understand that I need to parse the response once it is returned successfully.

Comment: You can use https://anotepad.com/ for paste and share the response. Also, have you tried https://colab.research.google.com/? - you can create a [mcve] sample there.